# Sparkfun Bluetooth modem

Tags: bluetooth, communication

Got a question about [the Sparkfun radio modem  WRL-08495](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8495).

A pair of these replace an RS-232 cable, right? simple as that?

What if my neighbor also has a pair of these?  Is there mutual interference
or is there encryption?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I get from the [FireFly User Manual](http://www.rovingnetworks.com/documents/firefly-ref-guide.pdf):

> **Overview**
>  The FireFly serial adapter is compact, versatile Class 1
>   Bluetooth serial adapter.  It enables
>   wireless connections  to any legacy
>   serial port and supports
>   bi-directional RS232 or RS422
>   signaling at a rate of up to 464Kbps. 
>   Just  attach the FireFly to your
>   device's RS232/EIA232/422 port,
>   connect over Bluetooth, and you have a
>   wireless cable  replacement solution.
>   The transmit range can be up to 330'
>   (100M), depending upon environmental
>   factors.
> FireFly Bluetooth adapter
>   can be used as a Bluetooth Master or
>   Slave device. The SPP connection to
>   the unit  appears via a virtual COM
>   interface.  Data is sent and received
>   on the client exactly as if a serial
>   cable was  connected to a real COM
>   port on the client.   FireFly can also
>   be used in cable replacement mode
>   where two Roving Networks Bluetooth
>   devices are paired  using the
>   configuration switches.  The USB to
>   Bluetooth (RN-USB-X) has pairing
>   switches and can be used with  the
>   FireFly BP to create a wireless
>   connection to a PC without using the
>   PC’s Bluetooth stack.

The [Cable Replacement Application Note](http://www.rovingnetworks.com/documents/cable-replacement-ap.pdf) indicates that proper [Bluetooth pairing](http://www.bluetomorrow.com/about-bluetooth-technology/general-bluetooth-information/bluetooth-pairing.html) is accomplished, meaning the channel is encrypted, either by small switches or with a serial monitor (they use [TeraTerm](http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA002416/teraterm.html), to which I give a thumbs up).

*Looks like a very cool gadget!*